# Why hashCode and equals methods are not working when a List implemented object stores its own object as a element in the list

Tags: java, list, collections

Why don't `hashCode()` and `equals()` work when a `List` implemented object stores its own object as a element?

Comment: Did you implement them correctly?

Comment: Where is the code which doesn't seem to be working?!

Comment: Share your relative code

Comment: That's an excellent question.  I don't understand why you're getting close votes and down votes.  I'll try to answer it before it gets closed.

Comment: @David I think people want a test case to show it happening

Comment: Not difficult - public class ListProblem {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
   List<Object> testCase = new ArrayList<Object>();
   testCase.add(testCase);
   System.out.println(testCase.hashCode());
  }
}

Comment: Anything can happen to code with type errors. When you have a list `List<X>` you can only pute elements of type `X`, not `List<X>` without committing a type error.

Comment: @DavidWallace A superclass of `List<WHAT>`? What is `WHAT`? It's not meaningful in Java (and most programming languages that don't allow infinite types).

Comment: `Object` is a supertype of everything!

Comment: In theory, this is a bug in the JDK.  In practice, the only application of a list that contains itself is to confuse students.  So I would argue that it's not worth Oracle fixing this.  It would also make the implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` simply horrendous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `List` bases its `equals` relation on the contents of the list. If one of the members is the list itself, infinite recursion ensues. The same problem occurs with `hashCode`.

Comment: Nice way of phrasing it.  I wish I'd spent my time writing an answer, instead of messing round posting the test case.  I have nothing to add to this.

Comment: FWIW I haven't profited from your test case---I was spending time writing my wrong answer :)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting for a moment that you had.  I know you're quite capable of working this stuff out for yourself.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So is there is any way I can store List instance inside its own instance and use it further. thanks

Comment: You could subclass the list implementation you are using and improve the `equals` and `hashCode` to take care of your concern. But I would advise just avoiding the need to have a list as its own member.